# How to create rows in pandas by dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem with pandas DataFrame - I don't understand how I can create new rows and merge them with a dictionary.

My theoretical situation, that I have daily reports from salesmen, who check whether `Network Name` have particular `Category Name` on their shelfs. All salesmen simply fill the report and indicate their visit as `VisitorID` and if a `Network Name` don't have any `Category Name` they just don't write anything.

I need to create a new report, where missing `Category Name` will be filled with zeros.

For instanse, I have next report:

```
shops = [{'VisitorID': '1434', 'Network Name': 'Sela', 'Category Name': 'Fruits', 'Value': 10},
     {'VisitorID': '1434', 'Network Name': 'Sela', 'Category Name': 'Tobacco', 'Value': 20},
     {'VisitorID': '1301', 'Network Name': 'Sela', 'Category Name': 'Fruits', 'Value': 30},
     {'VisitorID': '4012', 'Network Name': 'Mega', 'Category Name': 'Fruits', 'Value': 40},
     {'VisitorID': '4012', 'Network Name': 'Mega', 'Category Name': 'Tobacco', 'Value': 50},
     {'VisitorID': '4012', 'Network Name': 'Mega', 'Category Name': 'Vegetables', 'Value': 60},]
```

[image: Initial]

At the same time, I have a dictionary dataframe with `Network Name` and `Category Name` connection. Every `Network Name` must have next `Category Name` on their shelfs:

```
net_cat = [{'Network Name': 'Sela', 'Category Name': 'Fruits'},
{'Network Name': 'Sela', 'Category Name': 'Tobacco'},
{'Network Name': 'Sela', 'Category Name': 'Cosmetics'},
{'Network Name': 'Mega', 'Category Name': 'Paper'},
{'Network Name': 'Mega', 'Category Name': 'Vegetables'},
{'Network Name': 'Mega', 'Category Name': 'Tobacco'},
{'Network Name': 'Mega', 'Category Name': 'Fruits'}]
```

[image: Distionary]

So, in result I want to have next dataframe:

```
output = [{'VisitorID': '1434', 'Network Name': 'Sela', 'Category Name': 'Fruits', 'Value': 10},
         {'VisitorID': '1434', 'Network Name': 'Sela', 'Category Name': 'Tobacco', 'Value': 20},
         {'VisitorID': '1434', 'Network Name': 'Sela', 'Category Name': 'Cosmetics', 'Value': 0},
         {'VisitorID': '1301', 'Network Name': 'Sela', 'Category Name': 'Fruits', 'Value': 30},
         {'VisitorID': '1301', 'Network Name': 'Sela', 'Category Name': 'Tobacco', 'Value': 0},
         {'VisitorID': '1301', 'Network Name': 'Sela', 'Category Name': 'Paper', 'Value': 0},
         {'VisitorID': '4012', 'Network Name': 'Mega', 'Category Name': 'Fruits', 'Value': 40},
         {'VisitorID': '4012', 'Network Name': 'Mega', 'Category Name': 'Tobacco', 'Value': 50},
         {'VisitorID': '4012', 'Network Name': 'Mega', 'Category Name': 'Vegetables', 'Value': 60},
         {'VisitorID': '4012', 'Network Name': 'Mega', 'Category Name': 'Fruits', 'Value': 0},]
```

[image: Result]

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit hard than what I thought , we need first `reindex` after reshaoe with `unstack` , then find the correct one to fillna with 0 , since you do not want create additional row if all value are `NaN`

```
out = shops.set_index(['VisitorID','Network Name' ,'Category Name']).unstack('VisitorID').reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(net_cat))
out = out.mask(out.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x : x.ffill().bfill()).notna()&out.isna(),0).stack().reset_index()
Out[113]: 
  Network Name Category Name VisitorID  Value
0         Sela        Fruits      1301   30.0
1         Sela        Fruits      1434   10.0
2         Sela       Tobacco      1301    0.0
3         Sela       Tobacco      1434   20.0
4         Sela     Cosmetics      1301    0.0
5         Sela     Cosmetics      1434    0.0
6         Mega         Paper      4012    0.0
7         Mega    Vegetables      4012   60.0
8         Mega       Tobacco      4012   50.0
9         Mega        Fruits      4012   40.0
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't fully comprehend how it actually works, but it's awesome! Will try to understand each step, thanks